# How to post HTTP by post method

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection

I fetch latitude and longitude from the location manager but its doesn't connect with thingboard HTTP iot cloud. I used HTTP post response.it does not generate any error but it also doesn't transfer any data.since it is an AsyncTask it does not generate any error.i have encoded the latitude and long

```
    package com.example.currentgpslocation;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;


public class MainActivity<policy> extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationListener {

    LocationManager locationManager;

    String GPS_PROVIDER;
    String data;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

        GPS_PROVIDER = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);

        if (GPS_PROVIDER != null && !GPS_PROVIDER.equals("")) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return;
            }
            Location location =  locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);;
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(GPS_PROVIDER, 15000, 1, this);

            if (location != null)
                onLocationChanged(location);

            else
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Location Provider Found Check Your Code", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        TextView longitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        TextView latitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        longitude.setText("Current Longitude:" + location.getLongitude());
        latitude.setText("Current Latitude:" + location.getLatitude());

        try {
            Object latitud = location.getLatitude();
            latitud = latitud.toString();
            Object longtitud = location.getLongitude();
            longtitud = longtitud.toString();

            data = URLEncoder.encode("latitude", "UTF-8")
                    + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(latitude), "UTF-8");
            data += "," + URLEncoder.encode("longtitude", "UTF-8")
                    + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(latitude), "UTF-8");



        }catch (Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();

        }

        DemoTask  ob= new DemoTask();
        ob.execute();



    }
    public class DemoTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {


        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            String text = "";
            BufferedReader reader = null;

            try {

                // Defined URL  where to send data
                URL url = new URL("https://cloud.thingsboard.io/api/v1/JD98YCFBU8ywGIwVmdFL/telemetry");
                HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.connect();
                int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
                OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream(), "UTF8");
                wr.write(data);
                conn.getErrorStream();
                wr.flush();
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;


                // Read Server Response
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    // Append server response in string
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }


                text = sb.toString();
                wr.close();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            return null;
        }
    }










    @Override
    public void onPointerCaptureChanged(boolean hasCapture) {

    }
    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }
}
```

**Generate the Error :**
W/System.err: java.io.IOException: closed
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSink$1.write(RealBufferedSink.java:196)

Comment: @Vladyslav Matviienko .please rectify my error

Comment: Did you try searching the web for your error message?  https://www.google.com/search?q=android+httpurlconnection+java.lang.IllegalStateException%3A+Already+connected  Though I would try Volley or Retrofit rather than HttpUrlConnection.

Comment: now I ended up with new error:
W/System.err: java.io.IOException: closed--please help me in rectifying he code

Comment: Read the rest of the logging. Also, why are you not using something like Retrofit?

Comment: the error generated by the code:"java.io.IOException: closed."-what does it mean @nasch@zun

Comment: Did you try searching the web for the meaning of this error?  You need to develop the ability to diagnose problems and find solutions on your own, because it will not be practical to keep asking Stack Overflow for every little thing.  If you have already done so, then describe what you found, and explain what part of it you do not understand.  That might be best accomplished with an edit to the question, rather than a comment.